# Seeking Proof for Algorithm to Determine Acute and Obtuse Angle Bisectors of Two Lines in R²

Tags: analytic-geometry, angle

It has been taught to us that in order to obtain only the acute or obtuse angle bisectors of two lines, the following algorithm is to be applied:

$($Equation of angle bisectors:
${a_1x + b_1y + c_1 \over \sqrt{(a_1^2 + b_1^2)}} = \pm {a_2x + b_2y + c_2 \over\sqrt{ (a_2^2 + b_2^2)}}$$)$

1. Make the constant term of the concerned lines positive, i.e., $a_1x + b_1y + c_1 = 0$ and $a_2x + b_2y + c_2 = 0$
   $(c_1,c_2>0)$
   are the two lines to be worked with.
2. Next, check the sign of the product $a_1a_2 + b_1b_2$.
3. If the product is positive, then the equation of the angle bisector obtained with the positive sign is the obtuse angle bisector, and if the product is negative, then the equation obtained with the negative sign is the equation of the obtuse angle bisector.

I searched rigorously for the proof behind this algorithm but couldn't find anything helpful. Please help me prove this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: By giving Examples , you should satisfy yourself & others that the Algorithm works. That will have the additional advantages that your algorithm gets more clearer & the Proof might suggest itself.

Comment: I assume we have no Practical Examples showing the Algorithm to see whether it works ! Nothing more to talk here !

Comment: @Prem Developing an algorithm isn't a mere task devoid of mathematical proof. I seek assistance to substantiate my approach and avoid blindly accepting concepts, instead aiming to critically analyze, validate and rationalize what I learn unlike many.

Comment: When I asked for Examples , it was in line with "I seek assistance to substantiate my approach and avoid blindly accepting concepts" , where I am asking you to substantiate your approach with Examples , not blindly accept that approach without Concrete Examples. I am claiming that when you give Concrete Practical Examples , then that will not only substantiate your algorithm , that might also Direct us towards a Proof while clarifying that algorithm : So many Advantages !!

Comment: [[A]] **Hypothetical Algorithm :** When multiplying a number by $5$ & then doubling it , I claim that we can simply get the Answer by putting $0$ at the End. **My Example :** I will take number $6$ , multiply by $5$ to get $30$ , then double it to get $60$ , which I claim is just the Original Number with $0$ at the End & My Example works out. **My Proof :** I will take number $x$ , multiply  by $5$ to get $5x$ , then double it to get $5x \times 2=10x$ , which we know will End in $0$. DONE ! [[B]] You should try giving Similar Concrete Example to your algorithm & we can try to make a Proof.